# pull to refresh in listview

Tags: android, listview

i have implemented a listview which contains parsed data from a url, i have used lazy adapter for this.Now i want the list to conatins pull to refresh attribute but my problem is that i am not able to find a correct way to implement this, plz help

My XML for listview is :-

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upBar" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/latestList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

My Lazy Adapter is like this :-

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> movieThumbnail;
    private ArrayList<String> movieText;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    static File cacheDir;


    ImageLoader imageloader = new ImageLoader(activity);

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> movieThumbnail, ArrayList<String> movieText) {
        activity = a;
        /*data=d;*/
        this.movieThumbnail = movieThumbnail;
        this.movieText = movieText;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



    }

    public int getCount() {
        return movieText.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
              vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.rowListTextView);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
        text.setText(movieText.get(position));
        imageloader.DisplayImage(movieThumbnail.get(position), image);

        return vi;
    }

    public void clear(){
        imageloader.clearCache();
    }
```

and i am setting the lazy adapter in AsyncTask like this :-

```
@Override protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {


            lazyAdapter = new LazyAdapter(context, imgLinks, latestData);
            listView.setAdapter(lazyAdapter);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good tutorial you can use to do this:

http://sharedstate.net/archives/pull-to-refresh

Answer (score 0):

You may use *Pull To Refresh Views for Android* library

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh